# Why change what follows "no se limita" from "a cualquier locale..." to "a ningun lugar geografico"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos, definiciones, reflexivos

How is the following phrase better or worse than the one after:

> Afortunadamente, Dios no se limita a cualquier locale geográfico. (Fortunately, God is not limited to any geographic location).

> Afortunadamente, Dios no se limita a ningún lugar geográfico. (Fortunately, God does not limit himself to any geographic location).

Comment: "locale" is not a word in the Spanish language.

Answer (score 5):

"not" + "any" is usually translated as "ningún" rather than as a negative sentence containing the indefinite adjective "cualquier".

The sentence:

```
Fortunately, God does not limit himself to any geographic location.
```

should then be translated as:

```
Afortunadamente, Dios no se limita a ningún lugar geográfico.
```

That double negative is somewhat emphatic. If you don't want to be emphatic, you can also say:

```
Afortunadamente, Dios no se limita a un lugar geográfico.
```

This obviously refers to God's omnipresence.

Now, considering the religious content of the sentence, I think we could stretch the definition of [acepción de personas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0NO8Xkn) which is used in the Bible and say something like:

```
Afortunadamente, Dios no hace acepción de lugares
```

meaning that God does not favor one place over another (supposing that is the intended meaning).